Stripe JS based API - fetch list of products?
I'm investigating the use of the Stripe JS based API for my web app.
Looking at the JS docs,  I can't see a way of retrieving the list of available products. Is this possible?
TIA

This is the endpoint to retrieve a list of Products. Note that this code needs to be run on your backend server with a secret API key.
If you need the list of Products on your frontend, you have a few options:

Make a GET request from your frontend to your backend, then have the backend call the endpoint mentioned above and return the list of Products to your frontend.
Directly hardcode the Product ID (prod_xxx) in your frontend code

